# ImageView.setImageBitmap() is black

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to set bitmap as a source for imageview but instead of displaying the image, it just displays black color. There are no problems when I am running app on the Genymotion Emulator, only when I test it with galaxy s3 device. I've already tried reducing the bitmap size, using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`  method but it didn't help. I've tried suggestions on the other stackoverflow threads but none of them are working for me.

Comment: Can you post your code?